# Collections.sort() in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, object, collections

I am writing a `sortedAdd(T node)` method in `LinkedList`. How can I compare `node.key_` with `current.key_`? I can't use `<` (ascending order), since it's generic.

```
public void sortedAdd(T node){
  ...
  Node<T> current = header;
  while (current != null) {
    if (node.key_ < current.key_) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: change it to <String> ?

Answer (score 6):

[**java.lang.Object**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) doesn't **implement Comparable**.[**Collections.sort(List)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) expects `T` to implement Comparable.

**[From Collection.sort(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)**

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the
>   natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list must
>   implement the Comparable interface.

i believe your code should be:

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this mate:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("D");
list.add("B");
list.add("A");

Collections.sort(list);
```

To explain, the parameterized type (the one in the angle brackets) must implement the interface `Comparable`.

`String` implements `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
List<String> unsortList = new ArrayList<String>();

unsortList.add("CCC");
unsortList.add("111");
unsortList.add("AAA");
unsortList.add("BBB");
unsortList.add("ccc");
unsortList.add("bbb");
unsortList.add("aaa");
unsortList.add("333");
unsortList.add("222");

//sort the list
Collections.sort(unsortList);
System.out.println("ArrayList is sorted");
  for(String temp: unsortList){
System.out.println(temp);
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ArrayList is sorted

111
222
333
AAA
BBB
CCC
aaa
bbb
ccc
```